# FaunaDB Functions query data after Login

Tags: graphql, fql.multiquery, faunadb

I need some help with a FaunaDB function.

I have the following register function to register a User:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["email", "username", "password"],
    Create(Collection("User"), {
      credentials: { password: Var("password") },
      data: { email: Var("email"), username: Var("username") }
    })
  )
)
```

It works fine and returns the following output:

```
{
  ref: Ref(Ref("tokens"), "220428023135601160"),
  ts: 1603695853275000,
  ttl: Time("2020-10-26T10:04:12.646314Z"),
  instance: Ref(Collection("User"), "220412125733585420"),
  secret: "SECRET_STRING"
}
```

I want to change the function so that it returns the User Data according to the Ref of the instance variable `Get(Var("instance"))` and the `secret` string.
So that it looks similar to this:

```
{
  secret: "SECRET_STRING",
  user: {
          ... //user data
        }
}
```

I am tried to apply several functions but did not get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that might work for you?

```
Let(
  {
    email: "user@yahoo.com",
    username: "user1",
    password: "mypassword",
    document: Create(Collection("User"), {credentials: { password: Var("password") },data: { email: Var("email"), username: Var("username") }})
  },
  {
    secret: Var('password'),
    ref: Select(['ref'],Var('document')),
    data:Select(['data'],Var('document'))
  }
)
```

Luigi

Comment: Thanks  with a little modification of your query I got my result. I tried `Let` before but I used it not correctly.